# Swapping symfony form model in event

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I am currently working on refactoring parts of a cms api. We have a shared endpoint for fetching (via cget call) all pages/blog posts/shop items and so on.

What I am doing in the controller is to bind the request to a filter object via the symfony form component and then passing on the populated filter object to my repository to fetch the respective results.

I am in a bit of a struggle though. What I would like is for each kind of database document (using MongoDB here) to have its own FilterObject (so there would be a PageFilter class, a PostFilter class and an ItemFilter class for instance).

Now here comes the tricky part: I would like these different FilterClasses to be instantiated by the SAME FORM TYPE. So that I could submit the request to a form type that would return the suitable filter for the given request, based upon the request data.

However, it seems that one cannot change the option of the form (in order to change the model class) during the event lifecycle.

I thought about swapping out the model object in an event but that did not seem to work either...

Any idea would be highly appreciated !

Comment: You should share your code that shows what you're trying to do.

Comment: Use a base form, extend it, and override only the `data_class` option.